# Laurent Series for $\csc(z)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

I have to find the Laurent series for 
$$\csc(z), \qquad |z|>0 $$
but I really don't know how to start.

Please, guys.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**. One may recall the [Bernoulli Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number), defined by the series,
$$ \frac{z}{e^z-1}:=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}B_n\frac{z^n}{n!},\tag1$$
with $B_0 = 1$, $B_1 = -1/2$, $B_2 = 1/6$, $B_3 = -1/30$, and so on.

Then one may observe that

> $$
> \csc(z)=\frac1{\sin z}=\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\frac{2iz}{e^{2iz}-1}, \qquad 0<|z|<\pi,\tag2
> $$

and conclude using $(1)$.

Comment: Nice manipulation !